# Bash curl: Saving a file with a partial name of the URL

Tags: bash, curl

I try to save a file that I download with the name of the URL but it is not possible because of the folder structure in Linux. Instead, I want to save the file with the name after the last slash.
In addition, I need to somehow insert the file name into a variable (inside the loop).

```
url=$(tail -1 /var/script/string.txt | grep -oP '(?<=expanded_url":")[^"]+' | sed 's/\\//g;s@^@@'  |  sed 's|/$||')

for link in $url; do
    curl -k $url -o ./$link.html
done
```

Error output:

```
https://pastebin.com/11pn54uH
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file ./https://pastebin.com/11pn54uH.html: No 
Warning: such file or directory
100  1019    0  1019    0     0   2358      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2353
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 1019)
```

So, the downloaded file name should be like this:

```
11pn54uH.html
```

string.txt

```
{"created_at":"Mon Dec 17 08:15:55 +0000 2018","id":1074578927270678528,"id_str":"1074578927270678528","text":"https:\/\/t.co\/ISaiyHDHBy fdg fds g\n#osectraining","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":961508561217052675,"id_str":"961508561217052675","name":"Online Security","screen_name":"osectraining","location":"Israel","url":"https:\/\/www.onlinesecurity.co.il","description":"OnlineSecurity provides online cyber-security training courses and certification, from beginner to advanced with the most advanced virtual labs in the field.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":2,"friends_count":51,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":19,"created_at":"Thu Feb 08 07:54:39 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"000000","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1B95E0","profile_sidebar_border_color":"000000","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"000000","profile_text_color":"000000","profile_use_background_image":false,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/961510231346958336\/d_KhBeTD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/961508561217052675\/1518076913","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"osectraining","indices":[34,47]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/ISaiyHDHBy","expanded_url":"https:\/\/pastebin.com\/11pn54uH","display_url":"pastebin.com\/11pn54uH","indices":[0,23]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"fr","timestamp_ms":"1545034555629"}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `curl -O`:

```
-O, --remote-name          Write output to a file named as the remote file
```

Result:

```
$ curl -O https://pastebin.com/11pn54uH.html
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14336    0 14336    0     0   159k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  160k

$ ls
11pn54uH.html
```

Comment: Yes its good, but I need to somehow insert the file name into a variable (inside the loop). Can I do this?

Comment: @bugnet17 Can you edit your question to show what the last line of `/var/script/string.txt` is? Without it I can't really reproduce the output of your script.